# Scons : Can't Find Boost

Tags: python, c++, git, mongodb, boost

I followed to installation guide MongoDB C++ API compiling Tutorial in this [LINK](http://craftycode.co.za/2014/06/27/building-mongodb-c-driver-mingw64/)

1. installing-configuring mingw **SUCCESFULLY**.
2. **skip opensll**
3. downloading Boost and Compiling for MinGW **SUCCESSFULLY**
4. installing python and scons SUCESSFULLY
5. downloading MongoDB mongocss-driver at this [LINK](https://github.com/Climax777/mongo-cxx-driver.git) **SUCCESSFULLY**
6. and the last step when I execute the below
       command line at the msys.bat console

   scons.py --ar=`which ar` --cxx=`which g++` --mingw --boost-postfix=-mgw49-mt-1_55 --sharedclient --prefix=/c/MongoDB/MongoDB/ -j 7 install-mongoclient

following error occured.
[image: Error Ocuured during Compiling]

what is wrong here? I formatted my PC for this reason if any path is wrong.
Can somebody help me?
there is not error code like me at google.

```
C:/MinGW/bin/g++ -o build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_15.o -c -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Winvalid-pch -O3 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DMONGO_EXPOSE_MACROS -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x05010300 -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++\third_party\gtest-1.7.0\include -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++ -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++\mongo -IC:\Boost\include\boost-1_55 -IC:\Boost\include\include -IC:\msys\include -IC:\msys\local\include -IC:\msys\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include -IC:\c\Boost\include\boost-1_55 -IC:\c\Boost\include\boost-1_55\boost build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_15.cpp
C:/MinGW/bin/g++ -o build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_15.exe -fPIC build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_15.o -LC:\Boost\lib -LC:\Boost\include\lib -LC:\msys\lib -LC:\msys\local\lib -LC:\msys\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -LC:\c\Boost\lib -lC:/Boost/lib/ -lm -lws2_32 -lDbgHelp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Boost/lib/
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lDbgHelp
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: Configure: no


file C:\MongoDB\mongo-cxx-driver-legacy\SConstruct,line 1479:
    Configure(confdir = build\scons\sconf_temp)
scons: Configure: Checking for C++ header file boost/version.hpp... 
build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_16.cpp <-
  |
  |#include "boost/version.hpp"
  |
  |
C:/MinGW/bin/g++ -o build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_16.o -c -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Winvalid-pch -O3 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DMONGO_EXPOSE_MACROS -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x05010300 -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++\third_party\gtest-1.7.0\include -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++ -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++\mongo -IC:\Boost\include\boost-1_55 -IC:\Boost\include\include -IC:\msys\include -IC:\msys\local\include -IC:\msys\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include -IC:\c\Boost\include\boost-1_55 -IC:\c\Boost\include\boost-1_55\boost build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_16.cpp
scons: Configure: yes

scons: Configure: Checking for C++ library boost_thread-mgw49-mt-1_55... 
build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_17.cpp <-
  |
  |
  |
  |int
  |main() {
  |  
  |return 0;
  |}
  |
C:/MinGW/bin/g++ -o build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_17.o -c -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Winvalid-pch -O3 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DMONGO_EXPOSE_MACROS -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x05010300 -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++\third_party\gtest-1.7.0\include -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++ -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++\mongo -IC:\Boost\include\boost-1_55 -IC:\Boost\include\include -IC:\msys\include -IC:\msys\local\include -IC:\msys\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include -IC:\c\Boost\include\boost-1_55 -IC:\c\Boost\include\boost-1_55\boost build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_17.cpp
C:/MinGW/bin/g++ -o build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_17.exe -fPIC build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_17.o -LC:\Boost\lib -LC:\Boost\include\lib -LC:\msys\lib -LC:\msys\local\lib -LC:\msys\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -LC:\c\Boost\lib -lC:/Boost/lib/ -lm -lws2_32 -lDbgHelp -lboost_thread-mgw49-mt-1_55
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Boost/lib/
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lDbgHelp
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: Configure: no

scons: Configure: Checking for C++ library boost_thread-mt... 
build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_18.cpp <-
  |
  |
  |
  |int
  |main() {
  |  
  |return 0;
  |}
  |
C:/MinGW/bin/g++ -o build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_18.o -c -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Winvalid-pch -O3 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DMONGO_EXPOSE_MACROS -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x05010300 -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++\third_party\gtest-1.7.0\include -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++ -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++\mongo -IC:\Boost\include\boost-1_55 -IC:\Boost\include\include -IC:\msys\include -IC:\msys\local\include -IC:\msys\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include -IC:\c\Boost\include\boost-1_55 -IC:\c\Boost\include\boost-1_55\boost build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_18.cpp
C:/MinGW/bin/g++ -o build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_18.exe -fPIC build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_18.o -LC:\Boost\lib -LC:\Boost\include\lib -LC:\msys\lib -LC:\msys\local\lib -LC:\msys\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -LC:\c\Boost\lib -lC:/Boost/lib/ -lm -lws2_32 -lDbgHelp -lboost_thread-mt
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Boost/lib/
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lDbgHelp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: Configure: no

scons: Configure: Checking for C++ library boost_thread... 
build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_19.cpp <-
  |
  |
  |
  |int
  |main() {
  |  
  |return 0;
  |}
  |
C:/MinGW/bin/g++ -o build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_19.o -c -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Winvalid-pch -O3 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DMONGO_EXPOSE_MACROS -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x05010300 -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++\third_party\gtest-1.7.0\include -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++ -Ibuild\win32\ar_C__MinGW_bin_ar\cxx_C__MinGW_bin_g++\mongo -IC:\Boost\include\boost-1_55 -IC:\Boost\include\include -IC:\msys\include -IC:\msys\local\include -IC:\msys\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include -IC:\c\Boost\include\boost-1_55 -IC:\c\Boost\include\boost-1_55\boost build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_19.cpp
C:/MinGW/bin/g++ -o build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_19.exe -fPIC build\scons\sconf_temp\conftest_19.o -LC:\Boost\lib -LC:\Boost\include\lib -LC:\msys\lib -LC:\msys\local\lib -LC:\msys\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -LC:\c\Boost\lib -lC:/Boost/lib/ -lm -lws2_32 -lDbgHelp -lboost_thread
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Boost/lib/
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lDbgHelp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_thread
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: Configure: no
```

Comment: Which version of boost did you build, and where dit install it? (I am the author of the link)

Comment: You have a typo in your `extrapath` flag

Comment: @Climax i have typed --exptrapath=/c/Boost/

Comment: it should be: `--extrapath=/c/Boost/`

Comment: @Climax I wrote you said. I write here wrong comment. I tried a lot of way for compiling --extrpath, --cpppath, --libpath vs... still does not compile. occuring same error

Comment: can you please try from the beginning running the exact same commands as in the blog post?

Comment: @Climax i tried it with your tutorial more than one time,my compiler is MinGW32 but yours x64. may be this is a problem. anyway i stopped the struggle